# display contents of chosen .txt file

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, text-files

I have drop down menu as such:

```
<form id="page" name="page" mode="post" action="display.php">
    <select name="car" id="car">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select> 
</form>
```

I have this example of display.php from another user on here to display text contents:

```
 <?php
$file = $_POST['car'].'.txt';
$contents = file($file); 
$string = implode("<br>", $contents);
echo $string;
echo "<br><br>";
?>
```

This causes the page to change to the display.php but not display any .txt file contents.
When I use the foreach(glob *.txt it displays all the text files contents, for obvious reasons. But I cannot locate the error in my current config that would display just the chosen one. Please advise.

Comment: Don't use `glob("*.txt")`, just get the one file you want.

Comment: Do you know how to deal with forms in PHP? Do you know what is `foreach` loop?

Comment: @RocketHazmat i think that tripped me up and i'm looking into the solution

Comment: @barell i know little about php and am building as i learn and learning as i build

Comment: Do you know how to read POST data in PHP?

Comment: @barell I have a php that writes to whichever text file is selected with the $_POST statements in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you will need to have the data in the `select` box to be posted to the PHP file.

HTML code in `theForm.php`:

```
<form action="someFile.php" method="POST">
    <select name="car" id="car">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit value="Go"/>
</form>
```

This tells the browser that when the user click "Go", to send the data from the drop-down box to `someFile.php` where it can be used by PHP.

PHP code in `someFile.php`:

```
<?php
$file = $_POST['car'] . '.txt';
$contents = file($file); 
$string = implode("<br>", $contents);
echo $string;
?>
```

The `$_POST` array is a built-in PHP variable containing information sent to the server from a form.  The PHP then uses that text to figure out which `.txt` file should be read.  That file is then read from the file and `echo`ed to the user.

So if the user selected `Volvo`, this code will return the contents of a file named `volvo.txt`.

Comment: That does in fact display what I want it to, Thank you. but it opens the php results in a new page instead of showing it right below the dropdown like I'd like. What do I need to show it right on the same display as the dropdown menu?

Comment: That's complex.  There area lots of questions on SO about it, so try searching.

Comment: I found something to this effect.                              <script>
 $('#car').on('change', function() {$.post("someFile.php",{data : data}, function( data ) {
      $('#result').html(data);
    });
});
</script>                                                         I just can't get it to display for some reason.

Comment: Try this: `$('#form').submit(function(){$.post('someFile.php",{data:$(this).serialize()},function(data){$('#result').html(data);});return false;});`.

Comment: Sidenote: Part of your code in your comment above `f‌​unction(data){$('#result')` - there are 2 coded characters between `f` and `un` in `function` and appear as `f&#8204;&#8203;unction(data)` in my editor. Your suggestion should be changed to `$('#form').submit(function(){$.post('someFile.php",{data:$(this).serialize()},function(data){$('#result').html(data);});return false;});` which may not have worked for the OP. @SuperScript